# PyQT5: Why the program pass to the next line without finishing the process.startDetached command?

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I run this function I get the message 'installation done' before finishing the build. the startDetached method works fine but I don't want to pass to the next line before finishing it. So how to fix this error?

```
def toInstall(self):
    self.process = QProcess()
    self.process.startDetached('python', ['setup.py', 'build'])
    warn = QMessageBox.warning(QWidget(), 'Message', 'installation done')
    self.installation_done.setChecked(True)
    self.next.setText('Finish')
```

Comment: Then you should not use a detached process. Why are you doing it?

Comment: I find only this solution on the internet. Is there another way to execute a cmd command?

Comment: Did you read the [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) documentation?